# Hiding the navbar on front page using jquery

Tags: jquery, navbar, materialize

I have searched a lot on how to hide the navbar from the front page of my website(that is from the particle-js section) and display it when user interacts with other pages using jquery and it should also be responsive as well.

I have written the code in the jquery but its not working as expected.

HTML

```
  <section id="particles-js">
        <div class="navbar-fixed">
            <nav class="black">
                <div class="nav-wrapper">
                    <a href="#" class="sidenav-trigger" data-target="mobile-nav">
                        <i class="material-icons">menu</i>
                    </a>
                        <ul class=" hide-on-med-and-down">
                            <li><a href=#>home</a></li>
                            <li><a href=#>about</a></li>
                            <li><a href=#>project</a></li>
                            <li><a href=#>contact</a></li>
                        </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>

    </section>
```

javascript code

```
  $(Document).ready(function(){
            var previousScroll=0;
            $(window).scroll(function(){
                var currentScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
                if(currentScroll>0  && (currentScroll< ($(document).height()- $(window).height())))
                {     
                    alert("heyy");
                    if (currentScroll < $(window).height()){
                        window.setTimeout(hideNav, 300);
                    }
                    else {
                        window.setTimeout(showNav, 300);
                    }

                }
                previousScroll=currentScroll;
            });


            function hideNav() {
                $(".black").hide();             
            }

            function showNav() {
                $(".black").show();
            }
        });
```

jfiddle link : - https://jsfiddle.net/arunoday/uxnyctbr/5/

Comment: What happens when you scroll? does your alert show when you scroll below the fold?

Comment: the alert is not showing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `document` with all lowercase in `$(Document).ready(..`  and fixed code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.sidenav').sidenav();
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var currentScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (currentScroll < $(window).outerHeight()) {
      window.setTimeout(hideNav, 300);
    }
    else {
      window.setTimeout(showNav, 300);
    }
  });

  function hideNav() {
    $(".navbar-fixed").hide();
  }
  hideNav();

  function showNav() {
    $(".navbar-fixed").show();
  }
});
```

Comment: yes thats what i wanted but when i copy and pasted the code in brackets and run it, the navbar is hiding as expected but its not showing when scroll is coming in other div. So i tried to print the window.height value in the console.log and what i found is that its showing different value than the value shown in the jfiddle. here is the link of my github project : - https://github.com/arunoday153/myproject

Comment: change `.height()` to `.outerHeight()`

Comment: hey ewwink just need one more help.When i refresh the page the navbar is shown on the front page for a sec and then it hides.is there any sol. for this.

Comment: add css `.navbar-fixed{display:none}`